# after updating data in react context, how to re-render components under that context

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-context

My react application  has several components whose UI will  show up if the user is logged in or not. To share that state across my entire application, I made a context file called AuthProvider:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
      const user = decodedToken.user; 
      setUser(user);
      setUserName(user.user_name); 
    }
  }, []); 

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        userName, 
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

AuthProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

the main purpose of this context file is to check if the user is logged in, and if they are, send that information to all other components that need that information. If there are no tokens, that means the user is not logged in yet, and there's where my Login page comes in.

This is the Login page code:

```
import  { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'; 

function Login() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token){
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
            setUser(decodedToken.user);
        }
    }, [])

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const email = e.target.email.value;
        const password = e.target.password.value;
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {email, password});
            const token = response.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
            setUser(decodedToken.user);
            // if i remove this, I have to manually reload the page for the login to kick in
            // window.location.reload();
        } catch (error) {         
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {user ? (
                <div>
                    <h1>Welcome back!</h1>
                </div>
            ): (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="mt-4"> 
                        <div>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" name='email' required placeholder="name@email.com" /> 
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label >Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name='password' required placeholder="****" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
                </form>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

as soon as the login page is rendered, it will check if there is a token in the browser. if there is, it will decode that token and set its value to the state "user." in the UI, if state "user" is true, it means the user is already logged in and thefore will not render the login form itself.
If there's no token, the user will fill the form and submit it, which will trigger the function handleSubmit. In there, we will make an axios post request to my api, get the token of that user and set it to the browser storage, thus effectively making the user logged in as far as the AuthProvider context is concerned.

the problem is, after successfully logging in, if the page is not reloaded, it will still treat as if the user is not logged in. For example, in the Navbar component, certain buttons and icons in the UI will only show if the user is logged in. Only after I manually reload the page, it will show them. I was using the "window.location.reload();" to automatically reload the page after submitting the user login form, but for several reasons, I don't want to use that anymore.

why is this happening? I put the context file on top of of the hierarchy, above the the pages and components to make sure that every time a component or page get rendered, the context AuthProvider will check if there is a token in the browser storage and distribute that data throught the application, which after doing the login, there should be one.

this is the App.jsx file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <PageRoutes />              
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure if the PageRoutes component is relevant for this problem, but just in case:

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from "../pages/Register";
import Cart from "../pages/Cart";
import About from "../pages/About";

const PageRoutes = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route path="/" index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />} />
                <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default PageRoutes;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Your `Login` page is not using the context. I think you might have misunderstood the basic concept here... ?

Comment: yep, you're correct. I was only updating the user state that existed exclusively inside the Login component, so that din't carry across the other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of updating the state that's local to Login, update the state in the AuthProvider. Also, it looks like userName is just derived from user so i recommend you don't split it into a separate state

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  // ...

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      user,
      userName: user?.user_name,
      setUser
    }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Login() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  // ... the rest can stay the same
})
```

P.S, you should memoize the value you pass into the provider, otherwise you'll be making a new object on every render and forcing all consumers of the context to rerender even if nothing changed.

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    user,
    userName: user?.user_name,
    setUser
  };
}, [user])

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: I think you meant `value={value}`. Good idea with the memo

Comment: @Phil yep, i did. Thanks!

Comment: Only state changes would cause the provider component to re-render though, right? Since `user` is the only state, it seems like there's not a lot of benefit to the memoised object (happy to be wrong about that though)

Comment: `Only state changes would cause the provider component to re-render though, right?` Yes, but that includes a state change in a parent component above the AuthProvider. (admittedly, i have no idea whether that exists here, but it is common)

Comment: I have literally no idea what you have done, but it worked somehow. Thanks you both!!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to expose some way of mutating the context's state in order to have it update and propagate to others.

It's also a good idea to encapsulate the persistence method (ie `localStorage`) within the context provider. This makes it opaque to consumers and lets you more easily change it if required.

For example, in `AuthProvider`

```jsx
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

// encapsulate persistence
const setToken = (token) => {
  const { user } = jwtDecode(token);
  setUser(user);

  localStorage.setItem("token", token);
};

// encapsulate authentication mechanism
const login = async (email, password) => {
  const {
    data: { token },
  } = await axios.post(
    "/auth/login",
    { email, password },
    {
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL, // use env vars
    },
  );
  setToken(token);
};

const logout = () => {
  setUser(null);
  setUserName(null);
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
};

useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    setToken(token);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider
    value={{
      user,
      userName: user?.user_name,
      login,
      logout,
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

Then in components like `Login` you can use these context methods

```js
const { login } = useAuth();

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const email = e.target.email.value;
  const password = e.target.password.value;
  try {
    await login(email, password);
    // then navigate or whatever
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```